# If Nidalee uses Takedown(Q) in Cougar form, can she turn human and use it with her ranged Auto Attack?

Tags: league-of-legends

If Nidalee uses Takedown(Q) in Cougar form, can she turn human and use it with her ranged Auto Attack, So that her % health missing OP tanky AD ability is range?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Nidalee loses the buff after using her ultimate to change back into human.

Comment: Ah, I see what was being asked now. I thought they wanted to use the Q in cat then in human form.. Good to know!

Comment: It seems the opposite IS true though, if you AA, and go into cougar and Q while the AA is in still in-flight it will work.

Comment: @nightcracker this got fixed

Comment: @a13ph Unless it was fixed in this most recent patch, I do notice it every so often even though I don't play nid much.

Comment: @Katustrawfic can you somehow provide proof? video or replay? or at least clear description of how to reproduce? cause  2 heavy nid mains i follow state it's impossible now. and it was clearly stated in patch notes that it was what they fixed

Answer (score 1):

Nope, i just tried it in game. you need to stay in cougar form for that auto attack or else is dissolves :( sorry to burst your bubble.